# gRPC with API keys over ALB

Tags: grpc, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm developing a service that produces lots of traffic (about 200k RPS) and is called by other backend services. Previously, we have used an in-house JSON based RPC mechanism over HTTP, but rolling this out to some third parties. I'm therefore looking for exposing this as something more standard as well as trying to squeeze some bytes from the traffic, since we'll get callers from other AWS regions. I'm therefore thinking about using gRPC.

Our current situation is the following:

1. API keys used for authentication
2. TLS is terminated at the ALB
3. ALB uses path based routing (the service consists of multiple components)

My understanding is that gRPC refuses to allow API keys if TLS is not being used. Therefore, if the TLS is terminated at the ALB, then the setup won't work. If TLS is not terminated at the ALB, then a separate TLS connection is made between the origin and the ALB, so will gRPC detect this somehow and still disallow keys, since it's not end-to-end encrypted from the client to the server? Any recommendations how to set this up or some gotchas?